# Deploying lightning.viz server

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-visualization

I am trying to develop a custom lightning visualization. I was following this video on lightning custom visualization https://youtu.be/3kZxNGj15-s, but in the first step it said to install node.js to have a lightning server running. To do this, I followed the instructions on http://lightning-viz.org/setup/#deploy-server
I failed here:

```
 $ npm install -g lightning-server
```

This was my output for the first several lines:

```
npm WARN engine lightning-server@1.0.1: wanted: {"node":"0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"4.2.2","npm":"2.14.7"})
npm WARN engine hawk@0.10.2: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"4.2.2","npm":"2.14.7"})

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install /usr/lib/node_modules/lightning-server/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild
make: Entering directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/lightning-server/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil/build'
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
COPY Release/bufferutil.node
make: Leaving directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/lightning-server/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil/build'
npm WARN engine hoek@0.7.6: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"4.2.2","npm":"2.14.7"})
npm WARN engine boom@0.3.8: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"4.2.2","npm":"2.14.7"})
npm WARN engine sntp@0.1.4: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"4.2.2","npm":"2.14.7"})
npm WARN engine cryptiles@0.1.3: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"4.2.2","npm":"2.14.7"}) 
> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install /usr/lib/node_modules/lightning-server/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
```

I am running this software:

```
node.js: version 4.2.2 ;
npm: version 2.14.7 ;
gcc 4:  version  4.8.2-1ubuntu6 ;
java: version 1.8.0_66 ;
Ubuntu 14.04
```

Answer (score 0):

There are still issues with the newer versions of node and compiling the dependencies, see the issue here https://github.com/lightning-viz/lightning/issues/54

edit: the issue has since be resolved